# Started my first bootstrap theme not styling well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just started my first bootstrap theme, i have design in mind but the code i written doesn't showing output as expected,

[image]

with the design like (header + footer) [this](http://cobaltapps.com/downloads/catalyst/), and centered content are [this](https://justa.io/)

So far I have write this code, but didn't work well, 
if there is any expert, please help me.

```
<!--start: Navigation -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="border: black solid medium;">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taqi_Shah/9qbx6wxr/1/)

Comment: You need to add padding to body. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qbx6wxr/)

Comment: @anpsmn, submit your Fiddle as an answer.

Comment: @BSMP added as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a fixed navbar the content is starting from above and so its hidden behind the navbar. Add padding-top to body and it will work

```
body {padding-top: 70px}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qbx6wxr/)